# Opening up a QGIS project file on a different computer

Tags: qgis, save, qgs

I've tried doing this but when I save the QGIS Project to my desktop its only a few KB's so when I try to open this up on a different computer all the information inside the actual file is missing.  I'm wondering if there is a way to save all the data to a location or how to find where the data is currently being saved.

Comment: it needs to be on the same file directory (like d:/work/project/a) then on the other computer have a folder d:/work/project/a and your project will open. If there is no d: you can save it in offline project under database>offline editing, it will create a spatialite database which can be moved to another laptop/desktop.

Comment: Ahh I understand now.  Is there an easy way to re-reference where my vectors are looking to to open.  As in they are all trying to open up the shape files off my desktop so is there an easy way to point them to my network drive?

Comment: @Mapperz that's the answer to a question I posted to the QGIS user forum... how can we document this a bit more here...?

Comment: @DPSSpatial You can post your answer here and Jhunt9 can accept the answer. Have done this for many users of QGIS.

Comment: @Mapperz marked as duplicate... ah well..!!